# Detect if JavaScript is Executing In a Sandboxed Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a product that's playing a video in Flash (if available), and falls back to HTML5 if Flash isn't available.

I'm not able to find a way to determine if JavaScript is executing within an Iframe with the "sandbox" attribute, which is necessary for my solution because sandboxed iframes disable all plugins. The sandboxed iframe could be as simple as this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.cross-domain.com/" sandbox="allow-scripts">
```

To determine if Flash is enabled, I'm using swfobject's method of checking navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"].description, which is set even when in a sandboxed iframe. I can load the swf object, but it doesn't play.

To reproduce this issue, visit http://jsfiddle.net/max_winderbaum/9cqkjo45/, open your chrome inspector and click "Run". The script on the cross-domain site will pause in the context of the sandboxed iframe.

According to the W3 spec at http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/browsers.html#sandboxing-flag-set, there is supposed to be an "active sandboxing flag set" on the document that JavaScript can access (at least that's how I'm reading the spec). There doesn't seem to be any flag set on the iframe's document.

Does anyone have any ideas / solutions on how to detect if JavaScript is executing from within a sandboxed iframe?

Comment: But surely that's the point of the HTML5 fallback?

Comment: @minseong If you keep reading, the issue is that I have no idea of when I need to fall back to HTML5. Everything I can get from the browser tells me Flash is enabled, so I load Flash. If I need to load my HTML5 solution, I need to know if Flash is disabled in JavaScript. If you tell me how I can tell if Flash is disabled, it will resolve my issue.

Comment: What about document.plugins? That might tell you something different than navigator.plugins. The latter is the installed plugins, the former is (supposedly) the plugins in the document, which may differ due to being sandboxed. I haven't checked though.

Comment: In both a sandboxed iframe and outside of an iframe altogether, document.plugins returns an empty array in Chrome and Firefox. Good idea, though!

Comment: Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043278/how-to-know-if-a-page-loaded-via-iframe-is-within-sandbox (although neither has an upvoted answer).

Comment: Can you quote the portion of the spec which says that the sandbox flag should be accessible to JavaScript embedded in the page (as opposed to being handled internally by the JS engine or other parts of the browser itself).

Comment: May I suggest you go the other way around and always run HTML 5 video when using iframe-sandbox. I mean as the sandbox feature is HTML 5 and Flash is on its way out, why try keep it alive? ... And if no sandbox feature, no detect/run problems, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A project [sandblaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sandblaster) can help you detect if you running being sandboxed.

Sandbox check if itself is framed first and then scans through the attributes of the frame element to detect several information about itself. These includes `framed`, `crossOrigin`, `sandboxed`, `sandboxAllowances`, `unsandboxable`, `resandboxable`, `sandboxable`.

To detect if itself is sandboxed in our case, it checks if the frame element has an attribute `sandbox`.

```
// On below `frameEl` is the detected frame element
try {
  result.sandboxed = frameEl.hasAttribute("sandbox");
}
catch (sandboxErr) {
  result.sandboxed = null;
  if (typeof errback === "function") {
    errback(sandboxErr);
  }
}
```

I tried to replicate your issue and to test if this solution works, I had to paste the script into the window itself due to the security issue.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
        //Paste the contents of the script(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamesMGreene/sandblaster/master/dist/sandblaster.js) here

        var result = sandblaster.detect();
        if(result.sandboxed === true) {
            //sandboxed
        }
        debugger;
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/tzmn4088/ that shows this working.

Comment: Any chance you could add a little on how sandblaster does what it does to this post as well in case the project disappears in the future?

Comment: @TimB, Sure. I added some which I think is relevant.

Comment: This works great for me, even cross-domain. The key is in the _getEffectiveScriptOrigin() function. Basically, if you're in a sandboxed iframe, document.domain will be the empty string. Otherwise it will be set to something.

Comment: Here's an example with a debugger statement at the line that detects the sandboxed iframe: http://jsfiddle.net/max_winderbaum/q9ca0c8g/

Comment: @Omninternet, Nice one.

Answer (score 6):

I will consider different kinds of iframes (choose the first case which applies):

- **Iframes with the [sandboxed scripts browsing context flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#sandboxed-scripts-browsing-context-flag)**

  That is, iframes with a [`sandbox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute which doesn't contain the [`allow-scripts`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-scripts) keyword.

  This flag [blocks script execution](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#sandboxScriptBlocked). In particular, you can't use a script to check if the iframe is sandboxed.
- **Same-origin iframes without the [sandboxed origin browsing context flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-same-origin)**

  That is, same-origin iframes with no [`sandbox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute, or same-origin iframes with a [`sandbox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute which contains the [`allow-same-origin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-same-origin) and [`allow-scripts`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-scripts) keywords.

  In this case, you can use the [`frameElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-frameelement) global property to access the frame element (returns `null` when not used inside an iframe).

  Once you have a reference to the iframe, you can use [`hasAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-hasattribute) or [`getAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-getattribute) to check its [`sandboxed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute. There is also the [`sandboxed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-iframe-sandbox) property, which should return a `DOMSettableTokenList` (old browsers might return a string according to an old spec).
- **Cross-origin iframes without the [sandboxed origin browsing context flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-same-origin)**

  That is, cross-origin iframes with no [`sandbox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute, or cross-origin iframes with a [`sandbox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute which contains the [`allow-same-origin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-same-origin) and [`allow-scripts`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-scripts) keywords.

  In this case, the use of [`frameElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-frameelement) is blocked:

  - [According to W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-frameelement), it should throw a [`SecurityError`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#securityerror) exception. This is implemented by Chrome.
  - [According to WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-frameelement), it should return `null`. This is implemented by Firefox.

  Then, I don't think you can distinguish whether the iframe is sandboxed or not in this case. However, since using `allow-same-origin` in a cross-origin iframe isn't much useful, consider assuming the iframe isn't sandboxed.
- **Iframes with the [sandboxed origin browsing context flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-same-origin)**

  That is, iframes with a [`sandbox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute which doesn't contain the [`allow-same-origin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-same-origin) keyword but contains the [`allow-scripts`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-scripts) keyword.

  As in the previous case, the use of [`frameElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-frameelement) is blocked.

  However, you can detect this case because `document.domain` will be the empty string.

**Note**: Firefox treats data URIs as same-origin, so it's OK. However, Chrome treats them as cross-origin. Then `frameElement` doesn't work and `document.domain` is the empty string regardless of whether the iframe is sandboxed or not. You can check whether `location.protocol` is `'data:'` string to detect data URIs.

**In general**, you might try something like

```
function isSandboxedIframe() {
  if (window.parent === window) return 'no-iframe';
  try { var f = window.frameElement; } catch(err) { f = null; }
  if(f === null) {
    if(document.domain !== '') return 'unkown'; // Probably 'non-sandboxed'
    if(location.protocol !== 'data:') return 'sandboxed';
    return 'unkown'; // Can be 'sandboxed' on Firefox
  }
  return f.hasAttribute('sandbox') ? 'sandboxed' : 'non-sandboxed';
}
```

Comment: This works for me on Firefox, but on Chrome, it looks like trying to access `window.frameElement` from a sandboxed iframe throws an exception. Of course, catching the exception should be a reasonable diagnostic in itself.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Interesting, w3c says browsers should throw but whatwg says they should return null. I will update my answer.

Comment: Damn, it seemed to work well on Firefox for different domain too, but only [because of caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). Sorry Chrome for blaming you for not doing it well. Then this answer becomes somewhat superfluous. I will think if I can improve it someway, or otherwise I may delete it.

Comment: Because this doesn't work for cross-origin iframes, it's not really a general case as far as what I need it to do

Comment: OK, now this works for some cross-origin iframes, and a reasonable assumption can be made for the others.

Comment: I have tested that sandblaster library and it behaves like my code in all my tests, except sandblaster doesn't consider data URIs, so it produces false positives on Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately, my edits of your post were rejected, so I have to write it here: there are two typos in your code: `'unkown'` instead of `'unknown'`. If you decide to edit, you could also add the spaces after the `if` words as you did on the second line.

Comment: Regarding "using allow-same-origin in a cross-origin iframe isn't much useful":
It's useful to set that property so that the origin of the iframe isn't null. That way, it's possible to access the iframe's cookies or local storage from within the iframe. Having a non-null origin also allows things like accessing an iframe within the iframe. Careful, though! because it's only safe to set allow-same-origin if the iframe is cross-origin to begin with, otherwise it can lead to cross-site scripting attacks if it's the same domain as the parent.