# How to know if a page loaded via iframe is within sandbox?

Tags: security, iframe, sandbox

I'm trying to detect if a page is loaded via a sandboxed iframe. Is this possible?

For example,we provide custom embeddable widgets and some people think they are being smart by sandboxing them in their iframe, but this breaks certain things.. such as `window.top.location`

Obviously, they could enable the features we need, but ideally, I should be able to just do something like:

```
"sandbox" in window.top
```

I have also tried doing

```
try {
    // do something that would not work if within sandbox
} catch(e) {

}
```

But this doesn't work because it's a browser security error, and not related to javascript.

JSFiddle actually sandbox their iframes to prevent window.top.location navigation, so this would be a good example to show you. 
If you look at this example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwsb8geL/show/

You can see the error when you press the Instant Book Online button.

[image]

Comment: Yes, they are pretty identical questions. We both want to know if the current page is executing within a sandboxed environment. Neither questions have an answer yet. I've looked for a solution, I'll read the spec when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A project [sandblaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sandblaster) can help you detect if you running being sandboxed.

Inside the iframe where you are testing if it is sandbox, open up your script tag and paste the contents of `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamesMGreene/sandblaster/master/dist/sandblaster.js`. This is due to the security issue.

After this, its as simple as the following.

```
var result = sandblaster.detect();
if(result.sandboxed === true) {
    //sandboxed
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/tzmn4088/) I made for another answer but shows that the solution works.

Comment: I'm inside sandbox but getting `result.sandboxed=null`.   
   
I have an iframe with a form that when submitting its form with target of another iframe, I'm getting an error - `The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors.`.   
   
the sandbox attribute   
`sandbox="allow-top-navigation-to-custom-protocols allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modals allow-downloads"`