# Detect if iframe is sandboxed

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is there any way to detected if a iframed page is sandboxed or not?
I have tried the sandbuster js library but it no longer seems to work over cross-domain. 
I also tried to catch exceptions on window.frameElement, but it's always null.

The reason i am asking is the sandboxing feature is used by someone to bypass our protections and load our content without tracking and advertising.

Comment: Have you tried document.getElementbyId('frame_id').hasAttribute('sandbox')?

Comment: I need to find out from the iframed page, which cannot access the iframe id.

Comment: @VelDev Then, for all intents, it is sandboxed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if JavaScript is Executing In a Sandboxed Iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435076/detect-if-javascript-is-executing-in-a-sandboxed-iframe)

Comment: @jannis All the options described in that question no longer work.

Comment: Do you know what sandbox options are on the iframe?

Comment: Did  you resolve your issue ?