# JavaScript to Detect if Chrome is running with --no-sandbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

through JavaScript, is there a way I can detect whether or not the Chrome browser is running with `--no-sandbox` or if it is running with the sandbox enabled?

Comment: Maybe this answers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435076/detect-if-javascript-is-executing-in-a-sandboxed-iframe

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is in reference to Chrome's sandbox to prevent remote code execution from browser exploits, not to be confused with iframe or privacy sandbox.

Comment: Hello Sarah, did you find any way to detect sandbox / its absence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a V8 perspective: V8 doesn't know anything about Chrome's sandbox, so this isn't a V8 question. (Dropping the tag.)

From a Chrome perspective: I sure hope that there is no way to detect that. If there is, that would likely qualify as a security bug. So if you find a way, you may receive a bounty if you submit it at [crbug.com/new](https://crbug.com/new). Then again you probably already know that, since running without the sandbox is only relevant if you've already found some other exploit... On the flipside, that means that there's an indirect way to detect it: using the exploit you already have, try accessing the file system. If that works, the sandbox was off.